# OpenERP pentaho report error : Failed at query

Tags: reporting-services, odoo, pentaho

I am getting an error while I try to generate a report from OpenERP.

```
  File "/home/target/projects/orthene/pentaho_reports/wizard/report_prompt.py", line 207, in _setup_parameters
    report_parameters = proxy.report.getParameterInfo(proxy_argument)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1297, in single_request
    return self.parse_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1473, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 793, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
Fault: <Fault 0: 'Failed to invoke method getParameterInfo in class com.willowit.reporting.PentahoRenderer: Failed at query: SELECT name FROM res_partner WHERE customer=True'>
```

Here is how my pentaho report design looks like:
[image: version 5.0.1-Stable]
The pentaho report designed version is 5.0.1-Stable

1. It is a JDBC connection with my local postgres database connection, which is a successful connection in report designer.
2. select_partner is a SQL query that fetches all the partner names to show in parameter.

> SELECT name FROM res_partner WHERE customer=True

3. PartnerQuery is a SQL query that fetches name,city,phone & email of customers

   > SELECT name,city,phone,email FROM res_partner WHERE customer=True AND name=${partner} // ${partner} is a parameter defined
4. partner parameter is containing drop down selection of partners when we generate a report, it includes **2** point partner_query(which lists down all the partners)
   ![enter image description here][2]
   Report is working fine in Pentaho report designed & give output like this:[image]
   But it is not working in OpenERP & getting an error as described on the very top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a wrong value of pentaho.postgres.password in OpenERP Settings->Technical->Parameters->System Parameters.

This issue was solved after applying correct password.

Answer (score 1):

Keyur, I recommend that you post it on github page of WillowIT or this pentaho module.

Here is what I found https://github.com/WillowIT/Pentaho-reports-for-OpenERP/issues/125.

Is this query returning NULL?

Comment: No Rohit, query is not returning null. Report is working with the data in pentaho report but not working in OpenERP.

Answer (score 0):

The error

> Fault 0: 'Failed to invoke method getParameterInfo in class com.willowit.reporting.PentahoRenderer:

is a pretty generic error.  It is the top level of the error log from the Pentaho reporting engine when almost anything goes wrong, and is what is returned to Odoo (OpenERP).  As such, on its own, it is not helpful for working which of the numerous possible problems it can be.

Generally, the tomcat log file (*catalina.out*) can be far more helpful in working out what is wrong in the reporting set up.

There are a number of issues tagged with [Failed to invoke method getParameterInfo](https://github.com/WillowIT/Pentaho-reports-for-OpenERP/labels/Failed%20to%20invoke%20method%20getParameterInfo) on github.

Can I encourage people to look through the github issues and post there when looking for solutions.